# Using Fresh Masa with Tamales

Tags: mexican-cuisine, corn, tamales

I've always used the Masa Harina in the bag and made masa, but I don't have an electric mixer at the moment to make them fluffy. How do you use fresh masa when making tamales? Just add it to the corn husk and wrap? Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific with you problem, and the steps you take?

Comment: @TFD Thanks. I'm just making tamales and I need to use fresh masa. Do i have to do anything to it for adding it to the husk?

Comment: Yes, but there is no real standard other than oil/lard and stock/water. What recipe are you following?

Comment: I was following the recipe on the bag of Masa at the store. On the bag it tells you to make the Masa then the filling. To make the masa it says use a couple cups of the product, some water/broth, baking powder, etc. It then says to make it fluffy mix beat the lard and then add the masa. Do I do the same with fresh masa?

Comment: fresh rendered pork lard! very important to get a super flavorful tamale :)

Comment: You seem to be using the word "masa" to mean at least two different things interchangeably, and it's rather confusing. What's wrong with sticking to the words "flour" and "dough"?

Answer (score 2):

It's going to depend on the Masa itself. If it is just the fresh ground corn, then you still need to mix in your other ingredients, lard, stock, baking powder, etc, whatever recipe you decide to use.  Some places will sell fresh masa for tamalas already mixed up and ready to go, but it's typically labelled or sold as prepared masa.  Whether you have fresh masa, or masa harina, you will still want to whip your lard and make a light and fluffy texture before mixing in your dough, so an electric mixer is always a good thing to have on hand, or Popeye arms.

Fresh masa goes bad pretty quick, so make sure to use within a few days or freeze.